# Is it possible to write a .xspf automatically from a form? I'm thinking C#

Tags: c#, xml, playlist, xspf

I see it is possible to write an xml file in C#, but can I change the extension to .xspf?

The syntax is very similar when you do it manually

I want the user to fill a form with the attributes and a .xspf file to be exported.

Example, I want the user to be able to fill in the bookmarks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
<title>Playlist</title>
<trackList>
    <track>
        <location>./07%20The%20Punishment.mp3</location>
        <title>The Punishment</title>
        <album>Manos Hadjidakis: 15 Vespers</album>
        <trackNum>7</trackNum>
        <duration>125840</duration>
        **<extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>

            <vlc:option>bookmarks={name=omilitis1,bytes=-1,time=14},{name=omilitis2,bytes=-1,time=66},{name=omilitis3,bytes=-1,time=102}</vlc:option>
        </extension>**
    </track>
</trackList>
<extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
        <vlc:item tid="0"/>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string playListTitle = "Playlist";
            string location = "./07%20The%20Punishment.mp3";
            string trackTitle = "The Punishment";
            string album = "Manos Hadjidakis: 15 Vespers";
            int trackNumber = 7;
            int duration = 125840;
            string bookmarks = "bookmarks={name=omilitis1,bytes=-1,time=14},{name=omilitis2,bytes=-1,time=66},{name=omilitis3,bytes=-1,time=102}";

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
               "<playlist xmlns=\"http://xspf.org/ns/0/\" xmlns:vlc=\"http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/\" version=\"1\">" +
               "</playlist>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement playlist = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = playlist.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace vlcNS = playlist.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("vlc");

            XElement tracklist = new XElement(ns + "tracklist");
            XElement extension = new XElement(ns + "extension");

            playlist.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement(ns + "title", playListTitle),
                tracklist,
                new XElement(ns + "extension", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("application", "http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0"),
                    new XElement(vlcNS + "item",
                       new XAttribute("tid",0)
                    )
                })
            });

            tracklist.Add(new object[] {
                   new XElement(ns + "track", new object[] {
                       new XElement(ns + "location", location),
                       new XElement(ns + "title", trackTitle),
                       new XElement(ns + "album", album),
                       new XElement(ns + "trackNum", trackNumber),
                       new XElement(ns + "duration", duration),
                       extension
                   })
            });

            extension.Add(new object[] {
                new XAttribute("application", "http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0"),
                new XElement(vlcNS + "id", 0),
                new XElement(vlcNS + "option", bookmarks)
            });

        }
    }
}
```